# Comparison to exit status not working

Tags: bash

I'm trying to customize my bash prompt. I want it so change color if I enter a command that doesn't exist, or for some other reason fails. I'm fairly new with coding bash scripts, so I looked at some other scripts so get some help, but something's not working. Here's my code:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="
    PS1='`
        if [ $? -eq 0 ];
            then echo '
                \[\033[00;32m\]┌─\[\033[00;35m\]\u\[\033[01;32m\]@
                \[\033[00;35m\]\h\n\[\033[00;32m\]└─\[\033[01;32m\]
                (\[\033[01;35m\]\W\[\033[01;32m\])\[\033[00;32m\]\$';
         else echo '
                \[\033[00;31m\]┌─\[\033[00;35m\]\u\[\033[01;31m\]@
                \[\033[00;35m\]\h\n\[\033[00;31m\]└─\[\033[01;31m\]
                (\[\033[35m\]\W\[\033[31m\])\[\033[00;31m\]\$';
         fi`\[\033[0m\]'"
```

I do not have any linebreaks in the actual code, since that would be messy with PS1, I just added them to make the code easier to read.

So, I want to compare the exit status, **$?**, to *0*. For some reason the variable $? doesn't change at all in the script. It just remains *0*, so the first condition is always true, even when I issue a faulty command. I've tried adding *echo $?* to the code before the if-case, and this always returns 0, even if issuing *echo $?* as a command to the terminal returns something different. I've tried copying working code into mine, but that doesn't solve it either. Also, it worked when I used **'** as the outer citation and **"** as the second. I changed this because the script wouldn't accept **(** as a character otherwise.

Any ideas why this is and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your code is that that your quotation is broken:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="
PS1='`
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];
        then echo '
```

Generally it should work, try this:

```
PS1='`if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then echo Y:; else echo N:; fi`
```

Here is the output after applying the code:

```
$ PS1='`if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then echo Y:; else echo N:; fi`'
Y:
Y:
Y:
Y:false
N:
N:
N:true
Y:
Y:
```

Note: Simply pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, doesn't change the prompt.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. Unfortunately, your script does the same as mine. I changed it so it echoes **$?** if the first case, and it's still *0* at all times.

Comment: Once you've tested it, you've wiped out the original value in $?, if you echo it in the "then" clause, of course it will be 0, that's how you got there.

Comment: @Psyberion I added above the sample output. If this doesn't work for you the same way, you have any other weird problem. What is your `PS2` setting?

Comment: @Psyberion to clarify what @H.-DirkSchmitt is trying to say--the issue is that `$PROMPT_COMMAND` is wrapping everything in double quotes, which means what's inside the double-quotes is going to be executed at the variable assignment instead of each time you run a command.  You don't want that.  You want the ``PS1=`...` `` to be kept intact. You want something like: ``export PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1=`if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then echo Y:; else echo N:; fi`'`` *INSTEAD* of ``export PROMPT_COMMAND="PS1=`if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then echo Y:; else echo N:; fi`"`` (the inner quotes aren't even necessary)

Comment: Great, thanks! I got it now, and I tested and it's working great! Thanks a lot, to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Just as as a follow up to H.-Dirk Schmitt's great answer, this works for me (I'm not going to bother explaining the code, that has been done already better than I could);

```
PS1='`
  if [ $? -eq 0 ];
    then echo -n "\[\033\[00;35m\]\u\[\033\[01;32m\]@\[\033\[00;35m\]\h\[\033\[00;32m\](\[\033\[01;35m\]\W\[\033\[01;32m\])\[\033\[00;32m\]\$";
    else echo -n "\[\033\[00;35m\]\u\[\033\[01;31m\]@\[\033\[00;35m\]\h\[\033\[01;31m\](\[\033\[35m\]\W\[\033\[31m\])\[\033\[00;31m\]\$";
  fi`\[\033\[0m\]'
```

[image: bash colours]